# UTF-8 issue in linux

Tags: java, linux, utf

```
String departmentName = request.getParameter("dept_name");
departmentName = new String(departmentName.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")),"UTF8");
System.out.println(departmentName);//O/p:  composés
```

In windows, the displayed output is what I expected and it is also fetching the record on department name matching criteria.

But in Linux it is returning  "compos??s", so my DB query fails.

Can anyone give me solution?

Comment: You need to provide more info.  That code looks like Java... which Java runtime environment are you using on Windows, and which on Linux?  What exactly is a `request`... is that a database interface class, and if so, which one?  Which database?

Comment: request is ServletHttpRequest object and getting the request from Form parameters.

Comment: check `ServletHttpRequest.getCharacterEncoding()`

Comment: Why are you converting a String to a byte array and then back to a String anyway? What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the Charset `UTF8` doesn't exist. You must use `UTF-8`. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using unicode output with `System.out.println` is no good indicator since you are dealing with console encoding. Open the file with `OutputStreamWriter`, explicite setting encoding to UTF-8, then you can say if the request parameter in encoded correctly or not.

Second, there may be database connection encoding issue. For MySQL you need to explicite specify encoding in connection string, as for other, it could also be, that the default system encoding is taken, when not specified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to figure out the encoding you have in *every* particular place.

For example, the string might already have the proper encoding, if your Linux system is running with UTF-8 charset; that hack was maybe only needed on Windows.

Last but not least, how do you *know* it is incorrect? And it is not your *viewer* that is incorrect? What character set does your *console* or *log viewer* use?

You need to perform a number of checks to find out *where exactly* the encoding is different from what is expected at that point of your application.